# optimise multiple execution of same command - Docker

Tags: postgresql, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install and configure `postgresql-client-11` on my `ubuntu18:04`. I understand that we need to perform a few extra steps shown below to do the same (Source: https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/ubuntu-how-tos/how-to-install-postgresql-10-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts.html)

```
wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y postgresql-client-11
```

I am achieving it with the following

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get install -y wget && apt-get install -y gnupg2
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list
RUN wget https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc
RUN apt-key add ACCC4CF8.asc
RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y nodejs && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I am executing the same command `RUN apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade -y` twice.

Is there any way to **optimise the above and not have redundant commands**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak this a little, but fundamentally you need two `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` lines.  The essential dependency chain is:

- The last `apt-get install` line depends on having the upstream PostgreSQL repository available
- You can't `apt-get install` from a repository until you `apt-get update` from it
- You can't do that `apt-get update` without the preceding lines to add the `sources.list` line and load the public key
- You can't get the public key without `wget` and `gnupg`
- Which requires an additional `apt-get install` and preceding `apt-get update`

There's no particular need to run `dist-upgrade` twice and I'd skip it the first time (and maybe the second time: the Docker Hub `ubuntu` image is updated pretty regularly).  You can combine multiple `apt-get install` commands together, and if you have the `rm` clause in there you need to run it every time.  You also might consider whether you need a client library newer than what Ubuntu packages; if an older client library will work fine you can simplify this significantly.

So I might wind up somewhere like:

```sh
# Install prerequisites to install prerequisites
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      gnupg2 \
      wget \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure upstream PostgreSQL repository
RUN echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list \
 && wget https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc \
 && apt-key add ACCC4CF8.asc

# Actually install the packages we need
RUN apt-get update && \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get dist-upgrade -y \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      nodejs \
      postgresql-client-11 \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```